# D3 javascript/json wont run

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

i basicly just try to run this tutorial script, but i must keep missing something since i just cant get it to execute at all. Please lend me your eyes and help me out, thanks a lot!

original tutorial:
http://pothibo.com/2013/09/d3-js-how-to-handle-dynamic-json-data/

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

#demo{
 height: 200px;
 background-color: blue;
}


</style>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script> var JSONData = [
   { "id": 3, "created_at": "Sun May 05 2013", "amount": 12000},
   { "id": 1, "created_at": "Mon May 13 2013", "amount": 2000},
   { "id": 2, "created_at": "Thu Jun 06 2013", "amount": 17000},
   { "id": 4, "created_at": "Thu May 09 2013", "amount": 15000},
   { "id": 5, "created_at": "Mon Jul 01 2013", "amount": 16000}
 ]
</script>

<head></head>
<body>

 <div id="demo"></div>

</body>


<script>

(function() {
  var data = JSONData.slice();
  var format = d3.time.format("%a %b %d %Y");
  var amountFn = function(d) { return d.amount };
  var dateFn = function(d) { return format.parse(d.created_at) };

  var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([10, 280])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, dateFn));

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([180, 10])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, amountFn));
  
  var svg = d3.select("#demo").append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 200);

  svg.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter()
   .append("svg:circle")
   .attr("fill", white)
   .attr("r", 4)
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(dateFn(d)) })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(amountFn(d)) });
})();

</script>
```

Comment: Put the `script` after the definition of the `div`. At the moment, it's run before the `div` exists and therefore appends nothing.

Comment: thanks! fixed the order, but unfortunately didnt fix the script itself

Comment: Don't post code which generates console errors. Do you know how to look at the console? If not, please stop everything you are doing and learn how. The engine is much better (and faster) at spotting errors than a bunch of SO guys squinting at your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Typo

```
  svg.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter()
   .append("svg:circle")
   .attr("fill", white)
                 ^^^^^
   .attr("r", 4)
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(dateFn(d)) })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(amountFn(d)) });
```

It should be string `"white"`

Comment: Don't encourage posters who are using SO as a crowd-sourced typo-spotting service and don't even know how to view the console.